# PHP regex match excluded several urls

Tags: php, regex

I have a trouble with urls match! For example:
we have urls(strings):
/, /news, /news/1-addsf, /articles, /guides etc.

and task: get match of all, excepts all starts with "/news" (with or w/o continue "/1-addsf", need both regexp's) AND "/articles" AND "/"

i try smth, like this:

```
#([^\/news.*]|[^\/articles])#is
#\/[^(news.*|articles)]#is
#^\/(^news|^articles)#is
```

and manymanymany other variants

i think, that i doesn't know smth or am bad googler, but i can't find smth for this question.

Need worked regexp! Thanks!

p.s. sorry for my english.

Comment: it's not site where people helps with your homeworks

Comment: provide sample input along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like,

```
#^/(?!news|articles).*#is
```

The above regex matches all the url strings except the ones which starts with `/news` or `/articles`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nX7jC8/1)

Comment: That's it! Thank you!
p.s. may be change question, to do it more searchable? or any custom tags?

Comment: \b is not needed, but smth like this works correct ^/(?!$|news$) - it's matches string like "/news/1-asddf" and don't match "/" and "/news"

p.s. i don't know how type it correctly, sorry. but it's not a homework (for up comment) it's for simple banner rotate at site:)

Thanks!